# python basemap close to North pole

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot some data far North using basemap. Unfortunately I cannot get the meridians to be displayed. I think this is because they are not shown north of 80 degrees. Any way to fix this?

Basically, I use this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 8) ) 
m = Basemap(projection='poly', resolution=None,
            lon_0=16, lat_0=81.8,
            llcrnrlon=9.5, llcrnrlat=80,
            urcrnrlon=22, urcrnrlat=82.5)

m.drawparallels(np.arange(80. ,82.5 ,0.5),labels=[True,False,False,False])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(10.0, 22.0, 2.0),labels=[True,True,False,True])

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightblue')

plt.show()
```

which produces this figure:

[image]

But I want the meridians to be also displayed. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findings are some of many shortcomings that exist in Basemap. That's the reason why Cartopy was created. For a simple workaround to get your plot done, you can use `plot()` function to draw the missing meridional curves as follows.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 8)) 
m = Basemap(projection='poly', resolution=None,
            lon_0=16, lat_0=81.8,
            llcrnrlon=9.5, llcrnrlat=80,
            urcrnrlon=22, urcrnrlat=82.5)

m.drawparallels(np.arange(80.0, 83.0, 0.5), labels=[True,False,False,False])

# this does not fully work, only labels are rendered, but not lines
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(10.0, 22.0, 2.0), labels=[True,True,False,True])

# a workaround to get meridians plotted
phs = np.arange(80, 83, 0.05)
for ea in np.arange(8.0, 22.0, 2.0):
    lds = np.ones(len(phs))*ea
    m.plot(lds, phs, latlon=True, color="k", linewidth=0.5)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightblue')

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]